# WSO2 - API Manager linked to identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Based on the documentation, we have two ways to link API Manager with identity server:

- Using service provider (as federated)
- during installation by linking both users db together on deployment.toml level

What is the best approach and what should we choose in case we want all users of API manager (publisher, devportal, consumers of apis external and internal) to be defined under the identity server?

Comment: For having all users of API Manager (Publisher, DevPortal, consumers) defined under the Identity Server, the recommended and simpler approach is to use the Identity Server as a service provider (federated).